# pressBack() is ignored in a Espresso Test

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, barista

The Espresso's method `pressBack()` is totally ignored. I'm running the test on the emulator.

What I'm testing? Just calling an `Activity`, launching a second one, performing two backs, and checking that I'm out of the app.

Comment: Pretty sure it's not ignored. All my tests are utilizing the `Espresso.pressBack()` and they work as intended.

Comment: But the golden rule in Espresso testing is to **not** use the auto importer. You have to import the relevant package yourself.

Comment: Woop @MuratK.! Totally forgotten that rule! :·)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use

`import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.pressBack;`

or

`import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.pressBack;`

instead of

`import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.pressBack;`

Comment: import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.pressBack

Comment: Thank you so much, @snersesyan! Great contribution :·)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution there:

Stop using regular Espresso and start using Barista. There, clicking the back button is `clickBack()` instead of `pressBack()`, so it will never conflict with anything.

... and well, Barista gives a lot of more features, but I just got some karma points for this question, and asked myself *why am I not having this issue anymore? Oh, because of Barista! I should introduce it here.*

Feel free to check it out: https://github.com/AdevintaSpain/Barista

Comment: As far as I understand the only thing that Barista does, in this case, is calling Espresso "pressBack" method.

Comment: Totally, but thanks to the name change, it won't conflict with Espresso's ViewAction, which compiles but does nothing but driving you mad. It's just a convenient method that makes life an easier place to be. Actually, the whole Barista library is just a convenient thing to make life better, haha!

Answer (score 0):

**Use this for back press:**

```
UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()).pressBack()
```

Use this `implementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'` to implement UiDevice.